# GROUP_CONCAT with ORDER BY , but results are not ordered

Tags: mysql, subquery, order-by, group-concatenation

The following query works fine

```
SELECT
*,
(SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(url SEPARATOR '$$' )
FROM project_photos
WHERE project_id = projects.id
ORDER BY priority) AS images
FROM projects
WHERE catID = 2
LIMIT 0,5
```

but the `images` column are not ordered as priority. I am unable to understand why it is happening

## Structure for table project

```
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`catID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`featured` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
`featured_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `catID` (`catID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_catID` FOREIGN KEY (`catID`) REFERENCES `category` (`catID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

## Structure for table project_photos

```
CREATE TABLE `project_photos` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`url` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
`project_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=347 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: The `ORDER BY` is in the inline view, not the outermost query. That's why.

Answer (score 6):

[How to Order GROUP_CONCAT() Values in MySQL](http://biostall.com/how-to-order-group_concat-values-in-mysql)

```
SELECT
*,
(SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(url SEPARATOR '$$' ORDER BY priority)
FROM project_photos
WHERE project_id = projects.id
) AS images
FROM projects
WHERE catID = 2
LIMIT 0,5;
```